# Json like data to custom data type mapping gives error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am following a video on youtube of Flutter UI, In which the tutor is mapping JSON-like data to a more specific custom-made object class but doing the same is throwing errors to me. Might be because of the new Dart version?. Can someone clear the mapping concept to me as I have no idea and also how to fix this error?

Errors:

[image: Facing these errors]

```
  class CardModel {
  String user;
  String cardNumber;
  String cardExpired;
  String cardType;
  int cardBackground;
  String cardElementTop;
  String cardElementBottom;

  CardModel(this.user, this.cardNumber, this.cardExpired, this.cardType,
      this.cardBackground, this.cardElementTop, this.cardElementBottom);
}

List<CardModel> cards = cardData
    .map(
      (item) => CardModel(
        item['user'],
        item['cardNumber'],
        item['cardExpired'],
        item['cardType'],
        item['cardBackground'].,
        item['cardElementTop'],
        item['cardElementBottom'],
      ),
    )
    .toList();

var cardData = [
  {
    "user": "Amanda Alex",
    "cardNumber": "**** **** **** 1425",
    "cardExpired": "03-01-2023",
    "cardType": "assets/images/mastercard_logo.png",
    "cardBackground": 0xFF1E1E99,
    "cardElementTop": "assets/svg/ellipse_top_pink.svg",
    "cardElementBottom": "assets/svg/ellipse_bottom_pink.svg"
  },
  {
    "user": "Amanda Alex",
    "cardNumber": "**** **** **** 8287",
    "cardExpired": "03-01-2025",
    "cardType": "assets/images/mastercard_logo.png",
    "cardBackground": 0xFFFF70A3,
    "cardElementTop": "assets/svg/ellipse_top_blue.svg",
    "cardElementBottom": "assets/svg/ellipse_bottom_blue.svg"
  }
];
```

> **Second File**

```
class OperationModel {
  String name;
  String selectedIcon;
  String unselectedIcon;

  OperationModel(this.name, this.selectedIcon, this.unselectedIcon);
}

List<OperationModel> datas = operationsData
    .map((item) => OperationModel(
        item['name'], item['selectedIcon'], item['unselectedIcon']))
    .toList();

List<Map<String, dynamic>> operationsData = [
  {
    "name": "Money\nTransfer",
    "selectedIcon": "assets/svg/money_transfer_white.svg",
    "unselectedIcon": "assets/svg/money_transfer_blue.svg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bank\nWithdraw",
    "selectedIcon": "assets/svg/bank_withdraw_white.svg",
    "unselectedIcon": "assets/svg/bank_withdraw_blue.svg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Insight\nTracking",
    "selectedIcon": "assets/svg/insight_tracking_white.svg",
    "unselectedIcon": "assets/svg/insight_tracking_blue.svg"
  },
];
```

[image]

> Here in this second file when I changed map as <String, String> this error
> occurs but changing <String, dynamic> works fine. But why mentioning
> string is not working as these all are Strings in operationModel class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let Dart know what types are in `cardData` like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> cardData = [
  //...
];
```

instead of `var cardData`...

Comment: Thanks that's working. A little bit of confusion in another file when I explicitly mentioned that the map is <String, String> it's giving the same error but changing <String, dynamic> is working why? . In that file all of the class members are string only.

Comment: I'm not sure. You would have to show the code and error.

Comment: added the second file can you explain now

Comment: when you use the `[]` method, there is no guarantee that it won't return null, so it's of type `String?`, which can't be assigned to type `String`. However, the `dynamic` type can be assigned to `String` variables. You also could have fixed this with a `null` check, for instance: `item['name']!`, instead of just `item['name']`

Comment: it's related to null-safety, which you can read about [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

Comment: Ok, now I understood. Thanks a lot for clearing my concept of null safety. I recently started flutter dev and all of the tutorials are old at that time I think null safety was not introduced in dart.